# Who drew this depiction of Morpheus (from "The Sandman")?

Tags: vertigo-comics, the-sandman, art

I've been seeing this image of Morpheus - the main character of Neil Gaiman's *The Sandman* - quite frequently:

[image]
<sub>Slight variation [here](http://cdn.bloody-disgusting.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/sandman1.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YawTH.jpg)</sub>

It appears in multiple articles about the [now bust] *The Sandman* film; everywhere, of course, without attribution.

I set out to find the author, but [reverse image search](https://www.tineye.com/search/15a379fde297dd840f03921831e53bf2119904e2/) did not yield much. The oldest hits don't have any attribution; there is a ["tribute" pencil drawing](http://gi4nmarques.deviantart.com/art/Sandman-Tribute-362946380), but it doesn't attribute the author either (I [left a comment](http://comments.deviantart.com/1/362946380/4377007987) there; will see if I get a reply).

This art certainly doesn't look like anything I've seen in *The Sandman* trade paperbacks; it isn't featured in *The Sandman: Overture* either; neither in *The Absolute Death* nor in *The Absolute Sandman*. Not in *The Endless Gallery*, not in *Dreams and Nightmares Gallery*. Can't be found in Hy Bender's *The Sandman Companion*.

It looks *just a bit* like Morpheus from *The Doll's House*:

[image]

This one was penciled by Mike Dringenberg and inked by Malcolm Jones III; Google-fu involving  a combination of search terms still does not find the author of this art.

Evidence lead me to believe that this art as made after the initial run of *The Sandman*, and not as a part of the official publishing. So who is the author?

Comment: +1 for asking about my former computer background

Comment: @MatrimCauthon You fanboy :)

Comment: Guilty as charged ;).

Comment: Some more research that went nowhere, for future reference: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38957863#38957863 et seq. (Many of the more reputable websites in the Google Images search cited either "DC Comics" or "Vertigo.")

Comment: Still no luck. I have also been searching for the answer to this mystery for awhile. If it is the first drawing of Dream that inspired Gaiman then it has to be drawn before 1989.

Answer (score 12):

The artist is the German artist Lukas Frese.

[Neil Gaiman himself posted the same question](https://mobile.twitter.com/rockfool78/status/1233161537591877634) so I stumbled over this feed. Quite the lesson on how quickly images can get robbed and spread over the internet. Obviously the Sandman is Gaiman's IP and there is nothing the artist can lawfully do about the illegal spreading of his work, but it has been used in countless articles, mugs, t-shirts, even tattoos...

The original print was a birthday present to me back in 2010. He posted it once on his blog and it took a life of its own on the internet. Very happy and proud to see @neilhimself mention it. Great artist. Check out his work at [www.lukasfrese.de](http://www.lukasfrese.de)

Answer (score 7):

*Edit: Was a blind alley*

This appears to be a vector graphics work by deviantart member A-Scream: http://a-scream.deviantart.com/art/Sandman-Vector-463110397

> *"One of my first works in Adobe Illustrator."*

Being vectorart, it remains crisp when rescaled and therefore suitable for a variety of publishing formats, including desktop backgrounds. But it is regrettable (and typical) that the artist was never credited.

Comment: Possible, given the image is a vector art... But what about [this search](https://www.tineye.com/search/15a379fde297dd840f03921831e53bf2119904e2/)? It claims the earliest hits are from 2013, before that image was uploaded to DevianArt. I'll leave a comment to the author, see if they reply.

Comment: [There](http://comments.deviantart.com/1/463110397/4377145671), left a comment. +1 anyways, for finding a vector version ;)

Comment: If he doesn't respond on DeviantArt, I'll just try [Vk](https://vk.com/alexey.scream) :D Ah, the perks of speaking Russian...

Comment: Nope, that's not him - I asked him on social network, and he said he simply found that art online and decided to convert it to vector.

Comment: Ack! The wallpaper version at https://wall.alphacoders.com/big.php?i=195464 do seem to be the oldest one on the net.